# ComplexExpand does not fully expand

Tags: functions, complex, expression-manipulation

Consider

```
ComplexExpand[Abs[a+Conjugate[b+c]]^2,{a,b,c},TargetFunctions->Conjugate]

(* a b + a c + a Conjugate[a] + b Conjugate[b + c] + c Conjugate[b + c] +
  Conjugate[a] Conjugate[b + c] *)
```

why `Conjugate[b + c]` is not expanded as `Conjugate[b] + Conjugate[c]`?

Applying two times `ComplexExpand` gives the desidered answer:

```
ComplexExpand[ComplexExpand[Abs[a+Conjugate[b+c]]^2,{a,b,c},TargetFunctions->Conjugate],{a,b,c},TargetFunctions->Conjugate]
(* a b+a c+a Conjugate[a]+b Conjugate[b]+c Conjugate[b]+Conjugate[a] Conjugate[b]+b Conjugate[c]+c Conjugate[c]+Conjugate[a] Conjugate[c] *)
```

If applied 2 times, `ComplexExpand` gives a different answer also if `a`, `b` and `c` are reals

```
ComplexExpand[Abs[a+Conjugate[b+c]]^2,TargetFunctions->Conjugate]
ComplexExpand[%,TargetFunctions->Conjugate]
(* a^2 + a b + a c + a Conjugate[b + c] + b Conjugate[b + c] + 
 c Conjugate[b + c] *)
(* a^2 + 2 a b + b^2 + 2 a c + 2 b c + c^2 *)
```

Is there a reason why `ComplexExpand` doesn't "fully" expand?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `ComplexExpand[Abs[a + Conjugate[b + c]]^2]`? `TargetFunctions` probably targets only occurences in the input expression.

Comment: Because I need an expansion with `Conjugate`. I need it because I use the expansion as the input of `D`.

Comment: So the Idea is this: let's say I want to calculate the derivative of `Abs[a]^2` respect to`a`, where `a` is complex. Since `Abs[a]^2==a Conjugate[a]`, I want the result to be `Conjugate[a]`. To get this result, I need the `TargetFunction->Conjugate`. After expanding `Abs[a]^2==a Conjugate[a]` I substitute `a Conjugate[a]->a aConj` and take `D[a aConj,a]`

Comment: `Abs[a]^2` is not complex differentiable.

Comment: Well, `Abs[a]^2` is not differentiable everywhere. I'm interested in regions where it is holomorphic.

Comment: It is holomorphic nowhere.

Comment: It is holomorphic in the origin. Anyway the story is a little bit longer. In quantum field theory we have a function `L` (Lagrangian) function of complex variables (fields), let's say `z`, `w` and `t`. If we need, for example, the numerical coefficient that multiplies specifically `Conjugate[z] w^2` and not other variables such as `z`, `w^3`, `t` ecc. it is computationally common to take the derivative in the origin `D[L,Conjugate[z],w,w]/.{z->0,Conjugate[z]->0,w->0,Conjugate[w]->0,t->0,Conjugate[t]->0}`

Comment: So in the function L must appear all the variables `z`, `Conjugate[z]`, `w`, `Conjugate[z]`, `t` and `Conjugate[t]`. This is why I need the expansion with `TargetFunction->Conjugate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name notwithstanding, full "expansion" is not part of the charter of `ComplexExpand`. Rather it has the task of rewriting into an (almost everywhere) equivalent expression, separating into explicitly real and imaginary parts, and using only the provided target functions.

A method that will sometimes work to get full expansion in terms of variables and their explicit conjugates is to apply `ComplexExpand` twice, first separating using `Re` and `Im` and then using `Conjugate`.

```
ComplexExpand[
 ComplexExpand[Abs[a + Conjugate[b + c]]^2, {a, b, c}, 
  TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], {a, b, c}, 
 TargetFunctions -> Conjugate]

(* Out[49]= a b + a c + a Conjugate[a] + b Conjugate[b] + 
 c Conjugate[b] + Conjugate[a] Conjugate[b] + b Conjugate[c] + 
 c Conjugate[c] + Conjugate[a] Conjugate[c] *)
```